# Is there a more efficient way of getting facebook albums with their cover photo by using C#, Facebook .NET SDK and fql?

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-c#-sdk, fql.multiquery

I want all albums from facebook and get the src property of the cover photo. This is where it became tricky. I wrote the following code to do this, but i'm wondering if this can't be done in a more efficient way?

```
var facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        dynamic facebookAlbums = facebookClient.Get("/fql",
            new
            {
                q = new
                {
                    coverPids = "select name, link,aid, cover_pid from album where owner = 56615007038 AND photo_count > 0 ORDER BY created desc",
                    coverSrcs = "select src, src_big,aid from photo where pid in (select cover_pid from #coverPids)"
                }
            });
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("fql query took: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Restart();
        var coverPids = ((Facebook.JsonArray)facebookAlbums.data).Cast<dynamic>().FirstOrDefault(i => i.name == "coverPids");
        var coverSrcs = ((Facebook.JsonArray)facebookAlbums.data).Cast<dynamic>().FirstOrDefault(i => i.name == "coverSrcs");

        if (coverPids != null && coverSrcs != null && coverPids.fql_result_set != null && coverSrcs.fql_result_set != null)
        {
            var coverSrcsFqlResultSet = coverSrcs.fql_result_set as IEnumerable<dynamic>;
            var coverPidsFqlResultSet = coverPids.fql_result_set as IEnumerable<dynamic>;
            var test = coverPidsFqlResultSet.Join(coverSrcsFqlResultSet, album => album.aid, photo => photo.aid, (album, photo) => new
            {
                name = album.name,
                link = album.link,
                aid = album.aid,
                cover_pid = album.cover_pid,
                src = photo.src,
                src_big = photo.src_big
            });
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("processing took: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

The times are now as follows when performing this 10 times in a loop:

- fql query took: 717
- processing took: 204
- fql query took: 304
- processing took: 0
- fql query took: 265
- processing took: 0
- fql query took: 251
- processing took: 0
- fql query took: 220
- processing took: 0
- fql query took: 237
- processing took: 0
- fql query took: 225
- processing took: 0
- fql query took: 224
- processing took: 0
- fql query took: 225
- processing took: 0
- fql query took: 219
- processing took: 0

Comment: maybe if you post the times of the "fql query" and the "processing" someone can help you improve the code

Comment: done! 608 and 249 milliseconds.

Comment: maybe you can have a thread that starts to take the first album image and title and start to show it, so that albums start to appear as they load

Comment: I'm having hard time to believe the processing took 250ms..

Comment: @on5sl can you please put this within a for loop, and run it 20 times or so..? so you'll get some sort of average for the timing

Comment: When i do this 10 times:
fql query took: 717
processing took: 204
fql query took: 304
processing took: 0
fql query took: 265
processing took: 0
fql query took: 251
processing took: 0
fql query took: 220
processing took: 0
fql query took: 237
processing took: 0
fql query took: 225
processing took: 0
fql query took: 224
processing took: 0
fql query took: 225
processing took: 0
fql query took: 219
processing took: 0